# Проблема передачи данных из WI-FI очков если одновременно работает мобильный интернет

Tags: android, сеть, wifi, камера, streaming

Проблема такая. Требуется подключить WiFi камеру к телефону и сделать рестриминг red5pro. Я использую этот код для подключения к интернету

```
val connectivityManager =
        mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
val builder = NetworkRequest.Builder()
builder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)

val networkRequest = builder.build()
        connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback())
connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(
        networkRequest,
        object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network)
            }
        }
```

В этом случае возникает проблема, интернет активен, но изображения с камеры не получаю. А без этого кода, наоборот, я получаю изображение, но у меня нет интернета.

При использовании Speedify все работает, и я получаю изображение, и у меня есть интернет.

Мой вопрос: можно ли получить то же самое без использования speedify, если да, то как?

Comment: Я так понимаю, WiFi без интернета? Speedify возможно вам просто мост между интерфейсами выставляет.

Comment: Да, да, именно это и нужно. Можете подсказать как именно можно это сделать ?

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja

Comment: builder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) уж точно не нужно добавлять)

Comment: @eri все равно и без этого результат тот же )